# How can I make a specific page not https

Tags: .htaccess

So, I use a chat script called [AJAX-Chat](https://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/)

it works fine, but only when I take away the part of my .htaccess file that makes my site always go to `https://`
I need a way for a SPECIFIC directory to not be `https://`

My `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: why not fix the script instead?

Comment: It's not mine https://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/

Answer (score 2):

Add this above your other rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(Directory_to_exclude)($|/) - [L]
```

it will exclude that directory from forced to HTTPS.

Alternate(ther are lots)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !exclude_me [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```